# CefSharp PrintToPdfAsync saves a blank pdf when url is blob

Tags: c#, webforms, cefsharp

When I use PrintToPdfAsync() on a normal url it works fine but when I use a blob url (blob:https://someurl/12345#toolbar=0) only a blank page pdf is saved. .Print() works but I need to save the pdf programmatically. Im not sure if I did miss something

await chromiumWebBrowser1.PrintToPdfAsync(@"C:\a.pdf")